# Login failed for user 'XYZ' Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, semantic-web, d2rq

I'm trying to map the content of a relational database to RDF using D2RQ. 

To generate-mapping I'm using Command Prompt. I’m trying to access the SQL Server database but I’m getting the error:

Database Connection to jdbc:sqlserver://servername;databaseName=.. failed.
Login failed for user 'XYZ'.

I’ve checked the SQL error log:

- Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
- Login failed for user 'NT Service\ReportServer'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT:192.168.29.1]

[image: see error screenshot]

While in SQL Server i can open the database with this user.

Connection properties on SQL Server:
[see Connection Properties on SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txfky.png)

Comment: The login name in the error log is a different one from that shown in the command prompt. Are you sure the two things are related?

Comment: When i set Windows Authentication mode on SQL server i got that error, but i dont know why the user is NT Service\ReportServer.

Comment: @MartinSmith I dont know. But i got this error when i set Windows authentication mode on SQL Server, while my current user is DESKTOP-K7vR6PJ\Gresa-PC

Answer (score 1):

My team lead, pointed out the issue. As I could not find the issue/solution here, posting it for others.

I knew I could not use windows authentication, so I was trying to use SQL Server Authentication, this was the problem.

To access SSMS as a different user - When opening SSMS from your PC; Shift + right click > ‘Run as Different User’ enter ID ‘Admin1’ + password, proceed as normal.